# Should std::sort work with lambda function in c++0x/c++11?

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11

I tried to use lambda function with `sort`, but was getting "Segmentation fault" errors. I managed to simplify the code to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  const int len = 18;
  int intArr[len];
  for (int i=0;i<len;i++) intArr[i]=1000+i;
  // The following is expected to sort all but the last element of the array
  std::sort(intArr, intArr + len -1, [](int a, int b)
    {
      std::cout<<"("<<a<<", "<<b<<")\n";
      return (a<b?-1:(a>b?1:0));
    });
  return 0;
}
```

I compile and run this code in Ubuntu 11.04 (x64) using

`g++ -std=gnu++0x test2.cpp && ./a.out`.

It prints a lot of pairs of the form (large_integer, 1008), a couple of (0, 1008) and exits with "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Just as a remark, you're only sorting the first 17 elements with your code.

Comment: Yes. This fact is noted in the only comment of the code.

Comment: @KerrekSB: "// The following is expected to sort all but the last element of the array"

Comment: Ah, I was being blind! Sorry...

Comment: +1 for a well-composed question.  Its pretty rare to get a succinct question with actual, compilable code.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The comparison predicate should return a bool: true if a < b and false otherwise. Change the return statement to:

```
  return a < b;
```

Not to be confused with C-style 3-way comparison functions.

**NOTE:** Though C++20 does [introduce](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf) a 3-way comparison `operator <=>`, `sort` would still expect a 2-way compare predicate.

Comment: The reason why it segfaults with the wrong predicate is still a mystery to me.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: `std::sort` has undefined behaviour if the comparator does not impose a strict weak ordering. It's not that unexpected that a segfault could result.

Comment: I was returning an int (something like a.count - b.count) and got an incorrectly sorted list, instead of a segfault (libc++ with Clang). Returning bool fixed it.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: You can place a breakpoint in std::sort and see why it crashes.

Answer (score 16):

The predicate is supposed to implement a simple, weak ordering. <s>Also your range is off if you want to sort the entire thing.</s> (I missed that that was intentional.) So all in all we're looking for something like this:

```
std::sort(intArr, intArr + nelems, [](int a, int b){ return a < b; });
```

Or even:

```
std::sort(intArr, intArr + nelems);
```

The default predicate for sorting is `std::less<T>`, which does exactly what the lambda does.

Answer (score 7):

The predicate for `std::sort` doesn't take the Java-like `-1,0,1`, but instead wants you to return a boolean that answers the question 'Is the first argument less than the second argument?', which is used to weakly order the elements. Since `-1` is a non-zero value, it is considered true by the sort algorithm, and it causes the algorithm to have a breakdown.

Comment: "// The following is expected to sort all but the last element of the array"

Comment: @Griwes Huh? How's this related to the answer?

Comment: @Christian: I had an earlier edit that missed the comment in his code.  I removed it from my answer.  Griwes apparently caught it before I did.