# std::sort fails on std:vector of pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector, stl-algorithm

The following code crashes while sorting the vector.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    int x;
    // int y;
    Foo() : x(0) {}
};

struct Cmp
{
    bool operator() (Foo* p1, Foo *p2) const
    {
        if (p1->x != p2->x) return p1->x < p2->x;
        // if (p1->y != p2->y) return p1->y < p2->y;
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Foo*> v;
    for (int i=0; i<17; i++) // weird thing, doesn't crash if
                             // I put a number less than 17 !!!
    {
        Foo *ptr = new Foo();
        if (ptr) v.push_back(ptr);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Cmp());

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this so?

Comment: `if (ptr)` is useless, as the default `new` operator will throw if allocation fails, and `ptr` will always point to a valid heap section if it doesn't.

Comment: I just added it to make sure there's no NULL in the vector.

Comment: @miloszmaki, it's still useless.

Comment: You know it's like doing anything, just to solve the problem ;)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767998/should-stdsort-work-with-lambda-function-in-c0x-c11 for the modern, more compact way of writing this: `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](Foo* p1, Foo *p2) { return p1->x < p2->x; } );`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
bool operator() (Foo* p1, Foo *p2) const
{
    if (p1->x != p2->x) return p1->x < p2->x;
    return true;
}
```

`std::sort` requires a sort function that creates a [strict-weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). This *does not*. This is `<=`, which is not a strict-weak ordering. If `lhs` and `rhs` are equial then `comp(lhs, rhs)` and `comp(rhs, lhs)` must both return *false*.

Your function does not. Thus, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Changing `return true` to `return false` seems to help.

Comment: @miloszmaki: Of course it does. Then it becomes a strict-weak ordering.

Comment: @miloszmaki Dropping the `if` altogether would have the same effect :)

Comment: Thanks for help! I missed the most important thing in using std::sort!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Right. This `if` maybe looks weird, that's because I had more `if` statements at first. I've edited the question and added those `if` statements.