# Is it possible to use std::sort with a sort function that takes extra arguments?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, stl-algorithm

This is something that I've been considering for a while. I've done some research and can't find anything on it, but I haven't found anything to the contrary either.

Consider the `std::sort` function in `<algorithm>`. It takes two iterators and a function pointer as arguments. So if I wanted to sort a vector of strings alphabetically, I would do something like this:

```
bool ascending(std::string lhs, std::string rhs) { return lhs < rhs; }

std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), ascending);
```

The thing is that this type of sort function is case-sensitive, so would place a string beginning with lowercase 'a' after strings beginning with uppercase 'Z'. The only visible solution I see to this is creating an additional function along the lines of `bool ascending_case_insensitive()`. However, it would be nice if I could have a function `bool ascending()` with an additional `bool is_case_sensitive` parameter to use in sort. Is this possible?

Comment: That calls for a bound functor/lambda

Comment: 11 is perfectly fine.

Comment: You can create a functor class, and declare extra arguments as data members.

Comment: Could you punch out a quick example for something like this? I've never seen it used before.

Comment: examples over there -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767998/should-stdsort-work-with-lambda-function-in-c0x-c11

Comment: Pass strings by const reference or you copy them every time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Where you now have

```
bool ascending(std::string lhs, std::string rhs);

std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), ascending);
```

you can have

```
bool ascending(std::string lhs, std::string rhs, bool case_sensitive);

using namespace std::placeholders;
std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), std::bind(ascending, _1, _2, false));
```

The point of `std::bind` is to return an object that when invoked, calls the bound function, optionally with altered arguments. You can use it to change argument order, add optional parameters, or set parameters to specific fixed values.

Comment: `bind` is lame. Use lambdas. Also, AFAICS this solution will suffer from performance problems (not solely because of `bind`), won't it?

Comment: @Loopunroller If you want to write more code to achieve the same result, sure, go for it, but when there's a standard library function that does what I want, then I have no reason not to use it. I'm not sure what performance problems you're referring to, so I can neither confirm nor deny that those problems are real.

Comment: After carrying out some measurements it seems your code is slower by only a small factor, something like 1.1. My apologies.

Comment: Not a problem, that's still something worth pointing out. It's possible that the difference between a version with `bind` and a version with lambdas becomes less or more apparent depending on how `ascending` is implemented, depending on how `bind` is implemented, depending on the compiler's optimisation level, and perhaps more that I cannot think of right now.

Answer (score 9):

Since [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes an instance of the comparison functor, you can use arguments to your functor's constructor determine its behaviour. For example,

```
class StringCompare
{
public:
StringCompare(bool is_case_sensitive=true) : is_case_sensitive(is_case_sensitive){}
bool operator()(const string&, const string&);///This would handle the comparison using the is_case_sensitive flag
private:
bool is_case_sensitive;
};

std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), StringCompare(true));//case-sensitive comparison
std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), StringCompare(false));//case-insensitive comparison
```

Comment: Upvoting for providing a method that works with C++03. Sadly, not all of us are using C++11 or later and have access to std::bind().

Answer (score 2):

There follows an example that includes a function call with a bound extra parameter and a lambda expression that captures the extra parameter by value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>// for std::cout
#include <vector>// for std::vector
#include <functional> // for std::bind
#include <algorithm> // for std::sort

bool ltMod(int i, int j, int iMod) {
    return (i % iMod) < (j % iMod); 
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {3,2,5,1,4};
    int iMod = 4;

    std::cout << "\nExample for the usage of std::bind: ";
    // _1 and _2 stand for the two arguments of the relation iMod is the bound parameter
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),std::bind(ltMod,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2,iMod));

    for( auto i : v )   std::cout << i << ',';

    iMod = 3;

    std::cout << "\nExample for lambda: ";
    // lambdas are unnamed inplace functions
    // iMod is captured by value. You can use the value within the function.
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[iMod](int i, int j){ return ltMod(i,j,iMod); });
    for( auto i : v )   std::cout << i << ',';

    return 0;
}
/**
     Local Variables:
     compile-command: "g++ -std=c++11 test.cc -o a.exe"
     End:
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Thought that I would answer my own question in order to summarize the responses I've gotten. So from what I gather, I basically have two options.

The first would be to write a lambda function to handle my one-time case.

```
// Lambda solution.
std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),
    [](std::string const &lhs, std::string const &rhs)    // Thanks for optimizing my example code guys. No, seriously. ;)
    {
        return boost::toupper(lhs) < boost::toupper(rhs);
    });
```

The second, more reusable option would be to create a functor to handle sort situations like these.

```
// Functor solution.
class SortAscending
{
private:
    bool _is_case_sensitive;
public:
    SortAscending(bool is_case_sensitive) :
        _is_case_sensitive(is_case_sensitive);

    bool operator()(std::string const &lhs, std::string const &rhs)
    {
        if (_is_case_sensitive)
            return boost::toupper(lhs) < boost::toupper(rhs);
        else
            return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), SortAscending(false));
```

So think that pretty much sums up my options?